# How to use Detox waitFor with Animated Components that exist and return to screen

Tags: react-native, detox

## Issue:

Detox is not detecting when the element leaves the screen during a 2000ms timeframe.

### Expected Behavior:

- The animated component leaves the screen and then return back to the screen.
- The test will pass when the component leaves the screen during the expected time it should be gone from the screen.

### Actual Behavior

The test ends up hanging for longer than the set value and does not detect that the element exited the screen.

### Question/Ask for help

Is there a way to write a test so that when the element exits the screen it completes the `toBeNotVisible()` check and moves on to the next assertion such as checking for the element existing again within the animation time limit?

Also I found it interesting that if the interpolation for the Animated.Value is set to end offscreen the test resolves without errors.

Dependencies:

```
react-native: 0.60.4
detox: 14.0.2`
```

Below is the code.

```
describe.only('Animated Button', () => {
    it('should always be visible on the screen', async () => {
        const ele = element(by.id('animated-bouncing-button'))
        await ele.tap()
        await waitFor(element(by.id('animated-bouncing-button-container'))).toBeNotVisible().withTimeout(1000)
    })
})
```

Button

```
import React from 'react'
import { Animated, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const AnimatedButton = () => {
    let rotationDegrees = new Animated.Value(0)
    let isAnimating = false

    const handlePress = () => {
        if (isAnimating) {
            return
        }
        rotationDegrees.setValue(0)
        isAnimating = true
        Animated.timing(rotationDegrees, {
            toValue: 100,
            duration: 8000,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start(() => {
            isAnimating = false
        })
    }

    return (
        <Animated.View
            testID='animated-bouncing-button-container'
            style={[styles.container, styles.animatedContainer(rotationDegrees)]}
        >
            <Button
                testID="animated-bouncing-button"
                onPress={handlePress}
                title="Click Me"
                color="#ffffff"
                accessibilityLabel="Click to Toggle Animation"
                accessibilityHint="Toggles Button Bouncing Animation"
            />
        </Animated.View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    animatedContainer: value => ({
        transform: [
            {
                scale: value.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
                    outputRange: [1, 0.85, 1, 0.85, 1],
                    extrapolate: 'clamp',
                }),
            },
            {
                translateX: value.interpolate({
                    inputRange: [0, 50, 75, 100],
                    outputRange: [0, 700, 900, 0],
                    extrapolate: 'clamp',
                }),
            },
        ],
    }),
    container: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#00b7ff',
        width: 75,
        height: 75,
        borderRadius: 50,
    },
})

export default AnimatedButton
```